Ethyl ethanoate enolate reaction with Benzaldehyde
I'm a bit confused with this mechanism. The reaction is that of benzaldehyde + ethyl ethanoate with NaOEt, EtOH.
Under NaOEt, I'm quite sure keto ethyl ethanoate forms an enolate ion. I'm not too sure what happens with the EtOH and the benzaldehyde. Would this form an enol form of the benzaldehyde and if so how?? Also how would these intermediates form a product-- would it have to be a cyclic structure?
This product would then undergo a further reaction with 1. NaOH, H$_2$O, 2. H$^+$ where I think it is a hydrolysis of the ethyl ethanoate and some sort of splitting of the product.

I may be wrong but the reaction may follow a mechanism like the Claisen beta keto ester condensation except that here the enolate of the ester should attack the carbonyl of the benzaldehyde. After addition of NaOH, saponification takes place and the major product is a beta keto acid.

EtOH with benzaldehyde only forms a hemi acetal in equilibrium and is of no significance in the reaction.

This is a oneway condensation The ester anion will react with an excess aldehyde with no alpha H's. Hindered or no alpha hydrogen aldehydes do not do aldol type reactions with themselves. but can react with other enolates.

Your final product would be ethyl 3-phenylprop-2,3-en-oate after benzaldehyde-ethyl acetate condensation. Workup yourself the mechanism.
